# Pagination in smarty

Tags: mysql, pagination, smarty

I want to add pagination in my site when user search for some item. I have tried the following code:

```
//Array Declaration//
$pages = array();
$userlist = array();

//paging variable//
$userlist_pg = $_GET['list_pg'];

if(empty($userlist_pg))
    $userlist_pg = 1;
else
    $userlist_pg=$_GET['list_pg']; 

$userlist_limit = 10;//ADMIN_ITEMLIST_PER_PAGE;  
$userlist_start = (($userlist_pg - 1) * $userlist_limit ); 

$userlist_currentpage = $userlist_pg; 
$userlist_back = $userlist_pg-1; 
$userlist_next = $userlist_pg + 1; 



    $query_string = "select  cms_id,cms_variable,cms_page_name,cms_last_edited from  tbl_cms";

//Paging  variables start from here-------------------------
        $orderlist = array();
        $paging = new PagedResults();
        $paging->TotalResults = table_query_count($query_string);
        $InfoArray = $paging->InfoArray();
        $query_string.=" LIMIT ".$InfoArray["MYSQL_LIMIT1"].", ".$InfoArray["MYSQL_LIMIT2"];
        $PageVarName = 'client_page';

        $smarty->assign("page_display", getpagelist($InfoArray["CURRENT_PAGE"],$InfoArray["PREV_PAGE"],$InfoArray["NEXT_PAGE"],$InfoArray["TOTAL_PAGES"],$InfoArray["Second_next"],$InfoArray["third_next"],$InfoArray["fourth_next"],$PageVarName));
        $smarty->assign("currentpage",$InfoArray["CURRENT_PAGE"]);
        $smarty->assign("total_pages",$InfoArray["TOTAL_PAGES"]);
//Paging  variables end here-------------------------
```

it gives the following errors.

1. Call to undefined function table_query_count() in /home/www/jobplacement4u.com/hungry_uni/modules/search/action/search_action.php on line 110
2. Class 'PagedResults' not found in /home/www/jobplacement4u.com/hungry_uni/modules/search/action/search_action.php on line 30
3. Call to undefined method PagedResults::InfoArray() in /home/www/jobplacement4u.com/hungry_uni/modules/search/action/search_action.php on line 111

Comment: try table_query_count to $paging->table_query_count

Comment: `$userlist_pg=$_GET['list_pg'];` - Some nice [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you have here

Comment: can anyone provide me the complete solution or link

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to include the file(s) with definition of function `table_query_count` and class `PagedResults`